# buildozer for kivy, returns error

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, kivy, buildozer

I am a first time linux user. I am just following the instructions how make a mobile application via buildozer git hub.

Finally when i try, i get this:

```
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[INFO]:    Using Google NDK r9c
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[WARNING]: Could not find toolchain subdirectory!
[WARNING]: Could not find any toolchain for arm-linux-androideabi!
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[ERROR]:   python-for-android cannot continue; aborting
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3crystacks,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kivy/buildozer/something/crystax-ndk-10.3.2/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
kivy@kivyvm:~/buildozer/something/crystax-ndk-10.3.2$
```

have no idea what it could be.

i did following:

```
git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer
cd buildozer
python setup.py build
sudo pip install -e .
```

in buildozer i created a folder something.

within something i extracted Crystax NDK

within something i did `buildozer init`

finally i did `buildozer android debug deploy run`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides of installing buildozer with pip [you should also install](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#targeting-android) it's linux dependencies.

If you want to use specific NDK you should edit your `buildozer.spec` file which appeared in your project folder after you ran `buildozer init`.

Please take a look at [this short manual](http://www.albertgao.xyz/2017/06/14/how-to-deploy-kivy-app-to-ios-and-android/): it contains lines you should change in `buildozer.spec` to use Crystax and Python 3.